# MySQL's auto-reconnect in django

Tags: mysql, django, reconnect

How do you set the behavior of [MySQL's automatic reconnection behavior](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/auto-reconnect.html) in [django](https://www.djangoproject.com/)?
I'm assuming this is a client side configuration, correct?

Answer (score 1):

Django database wrappers have a method called [`is_usable()`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py#L546) that pings the server to check if it's up. This is the one for MySQL -

```
def is_usable(self):
    try:
        self.connection.ping()
    except DatabaseError:
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

From MySQL url you provided -

> If auto-reconnect is enabled, mysql_ping() performs a reconnect. Otherwise, it returns an error.

So it all depends on how you configured this part -

```
mysql_options(&mysql, MYSQL_OPT_RECONNECT, &reconnect);
```

which you have to set yourself on the DBMS.